# Adding new data to Jquery after clicking a div

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

Here is a code of FullCalendar that I am using:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var date = new Date();
    var d = date.getDate();
    var m = date.getMonth();
    var y = date.getFullYear();
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        header: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'agendaWeek,agendaDay'
        },
        editable: true,
        events: [
            {
                title: 'All Day Event',
                start: new Date(y, m, 1),
            },
            {
                title: 'Long Event',
                start: new Date(y, m, d-5),
                end: new Date(y, m, d-2)
            }
        ]
    });
});
```

I have a `<a>` element in the page and when I click on that link, I need to add following data to event of the calendar and the event should be became like this

```
events: [
    {
        title: 'All Day Event',
        start: new Date(y, m, 1),
    },
    {
        title: 'Meet Thomas Antony',
        start: new Date(y, m, 1),
    },
    {
        title: 'Meet Mathew',
        start: new Date(y, m, 1),
    },
    {
        title: 'Long Event',
        start: new Date(y, m, d-5),
        end: new Date(y, m, d-2)
    }
]
```

Which means this...:

```
{
    title: 'Meet Thomas Antony',
    start: new Date(y, m, 1),
},
{
    title: 'Meet Mathew',
    start: new Date(y, m, 1),
},
```

... should be added to events at the time of clicking a link tag. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a [`renderEvent`](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_rendering/renderEvent/) method in fullCalendar for this:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar('renderEvent', {
  title: 'Meet Thomas Antony',
  start: new Date(y, m, 1)
}, true).fullCalendar('addEvent', {
  title: 'Meet Mathew',
  start: new Date(y, m, 1)
}, true);
```

In a full example you'd be looping though a collection, but you get the idea, just call `.fullCalendar('renderEvent', eventObject, true)`.  For a full event object property listing, [look here](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_data/Event_Object/).  The last parameter is optional, depending of if you refresh the event data source later...if you want it to say in that case, set it to `true`, otherwise you can leave it off.

Comment: I Used the following code but it not working $(".ma").click(function () { 
     $('#calendar').fullCalendar('addEvent', {
  title: 'Meet Thomas Antony',
  start: new Date(y, m, 1)

})

    });

Comment: @Alex - Apologies I haven't used this in a few versions (demo page was using 1.2), check the updated answer, the API changed a bit to `renderEvent` instead now.

Comment: @Alex - you want to add them, then hide them?

Comment: yes.....do we have any option for that, like when i click link ones,show them,and if i click one more hide them

Comment: @Alex - The best way to do that would be to give them a CSS class by specifying `className` on the event object, for example: `{ title: 'Meet Mathew', start: new Date(y, m, 1), className: 'meeting' }` then in those buttons, `$(".meeting").hide();` and `$(".meeting").show()` to show/hide those events.